# Is there a way to get a live preview of my web project while working on Razor views in Visual Studio 2022 using .net Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I've succesfully use **BrowserLink** to edit my `css` and get a live preview on saving the file, but would like that the page refresh itself while changing the `HTML` in my Razor views.

**Is there a way to do it?**

This is NOT `.net Core` It's old regular .net Framework

Answer (score 2):

You can use Web Live Preview for this. This is a preview feature in VS2022. You can enable this in Tools->Options

[image]

After enabling that, close and reopen the view files you want to preview. You should see a Design and Split button.

[image]

Then you should get a preview of your project.

[image]

This is limited to ASP.NET Framework project for now, we may add support for ASP.NET Core in the future.

Comment: I tried to make it work, but the page get stuck at "Generating Logical Tree". Since all the docs says that this is a WebForms feature, I've assumed that this was the reason that does not work in my MVC Project. I will try to resolve my issue in another question